# DecimalFormat Not Giving Result as per Half_Even Rounding

Tags: java, decimalformat

I am trying to round to 1-decimal place. Below is the code snippet.

```
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#0.#");
String formattedNumber = decimalFormat.format(4.65d);
System.out.println(formattedNumber);
```

**Output**
4.7

As per DecimalFormat javadoc, its default rounding is HALF_EVEN. By this rule, 4.65 should have been rounded to **4.6**. But, it is giving output as **4.7**. Please help me understand this behavior.

Comment: @ChiragParmar this is not duplicate. The other question is about understanding basic of HALF_EVEN, this is not the purpose of this question. Rather, we are discussing the reason of unexpected behavior shown while roundin in the mentioned case which is not answered in the other question you provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A double has a small representation error for many decimal values, this included 4.65 which is actually slightly higher than it appears.

```
System.out.println(new BigDecimal(4.65));
```

prints

```
4.6500000000000003552713678800500929355621337890625
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you provide some reading material to understand more about this error representation in some decimal values. Is it specific to Java?

Comment: @sky it is the same issue for all IEEE 754 standard implementations. Google for links on this. Half even doesn't mean much unless the value as a precise representation.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Peter's Lawrey answer you could try to pass to `decimalFormat.format()` method `BigDecimal(String val)` to ensure passing the exact value:

```
String formattedNumber = decimalFormat.format(new BigDecimal("4.65"));
System.out.println(formattedNumber);
```

You will get an output of `4.6`.